# error calling bash script line 11: /home/tmp: Is a directory

Tags: bash

I defined the following bash function in test.sh

```
function escaped {
    path="$1"
    if [ $path ?? '\' ]; then
    return "$path"
    fi
    ret=${path//\\/}
    return "$ret"

}

a=escaped   $1
```

running the script:

```
-bash-4.3# ./test.sh /home/tmp 
./test.sh: line 11: /home/tmp: Is a directory
```

I don't understand why the error is happening.  what's the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `a=escaped   $1` is not doing what you expect it is.

You are expecting that you are calling the `escaped` function with an argument of `$1` (the string "/home/tmp") and storing that result in the `a` variable.

You aren't doing that.

What you are doing is running the value of `$1` ("/home/tmp") as a command with the variable `a` assigned the value `escaped` in its starting environment.

Compare the output from `env | grep foo=` to the output from `foo=bar env | grep foo=` for example.

What you want to be doing in your script is this instead.

```
a=$(escaped $1")
```

Assuming you want the output of the `escaped` function stored in the `a` variable.

Note: shell functions cannot `return` strings, only integers.
Note: `$()` captures the **output** from a command/function/etc. not the return value.